# how to combine fragments layout with navigation drawer layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

first I'm new to android ,so sorry for non clear points, I have 2 layouts: the first one includes fragments; the second one is a navigation drawer layout.

How can I integrate both layouts inside one layout ? i want to have main layout contain both layouts , please help ..

The first layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.HomeFragment"
              android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.example.SplashFragment"
              android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment"
              android:id="@+id/userSettingsFragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The second navigation drawer layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second layout declares a `FrameLayout` element. This element is used to integrate your `Fragment` dynamically. This practice is explained in the official Android documentation on [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: Dear Gerard Paligot sorry but i'm new to android i did check for fragments link that u sent , so as i got from link , i can but my fragments inside Framlayout ?? and assign which fragment will appear from MainActivity ???